# Definition of Expectation clarification

Tags: self-study, expected-value

In *Econometric Theory* of Davidson (2004) I read (p. 446):

> In terms of the parent probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$
>   this implies a partition of $\Omega$ into sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n$,
>   with $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ for each $i$, $A_i \cap A_j = \varnothing$
>   when $i \neq j$ [..] Approximating X "from below" leads to the formal
>   definition:
>
> $E(X) = \underset{{\phi < X}}{\mathrm{sup}} \left\{ \sum_i \phi_i
> > P(A_i)\right\}  \qquad (B.4.3) $
>
> where $\phi$  denotes any simple random variable assuming values
>   $\phi(\omega) = \phi_i$ for $\omega \in A_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$
>   for finite $n$ and $\phi(\omega) < X(\omega) $ for all $\omega \in
> > \Omega$

I am new to the notion of supremums. My question is why do we have to use a supremum? How would you explain this definition in words? That the expected value of $X$ is the largest value of $\phi_i$ times the probability of each partition $A_i$?

Comment: The interval $[0, 1[$ -- i.e. open on the right, which can also be written $[0, 1)$ -- has no max, but it has a supremum of 1.  That's an example of why you'd use a supremum instead of a maximum:  the maximum may not exist.

Comment: The sequence of symbols "$\left\{ \sum_i \phi_i \gt P(A_i)\right\}$" is mathematical nonsense. For this question to have any meaning, then, please edit it to explain what the author might have meant by it.